# How to improve display and handling of a large number of inlines in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, inline, large-data

When displaying an inline for a model, if there's a large number of inlines, the change page then loads slowly, and can be hard to navigate through all of them. I'm already using an inline-collapsing trick (found on [DjangoSnippets](http://djangosnippets.org), but the search there is not working so I can't share the link here), but still isn't easy to browse since they are named alike (mostly diferentiates in numbers) and all inlines are still loaded.

I need some kind of paginator for the inlines, and also that this paginator shows at first the most interesting inlines for the current object being edited, like specifying ordering for the onlines only (not the default ordering used in other areas of the app).

**UPDATE**: The inlines are all instances of one child related class.

Comment: It looks like the domain should be http://www.djangosnippets.org/; the `.com` site is an ad parking site.

Comment: A little more detail would be useful. When you say "a large number of inlines" do you mean a large number of instances of one related class? Or do you mean a large number of related classes? It sounds like the former is the case. Sometimes this is "fixed" by treating the child objects as separately editable items with a ForeignKey relation to the parent. I went this direction on a wine-critique website where a single article could have as many as 20 or more tasting notes connected to it (there were other factors, too, that pushed me in this direction).

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it's the first case, it's just one related class, but with a lot of instances (definitely 20+). When you say "separately editable items" you mean an independent ModelAdmin for editing the child object? In that case, it doesn't help, because since there are a lot of them, and it very much comfortable to edit the child object right in the parent's edit page, since it's common sense for the users.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to control the number of lists per page, you can set `list_per_page=50`

example

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
  list_per_page = 50

admin.register(model, ModelAdmin)
```

this solves pagination